# auth0-vue3 Setting up loginWithRedirect when URL has a query

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, redirect, auth0

So, trying to set up Auth0 loginWithRedirect for the specific issue of URL location routing:

Before, we would store a URL in local storage if it had a query, then after logging in, if localStorageURL !== null, we'd take it and route to that page; this worked until Auth0 SSO was implemented, and now, localStorage is wiped after login. Auth0 claims that utilizng `loginWithRedirect` alongside state parameters should fix the issue, however, there is no specifics as to how to set this up (in that, we've seen a ton of different ways in which people claimed to have implemented it, yet, they all vary)?

We have a `/callback` route that we want `loginWithRedirect` to route to after authorizing the user, which we will then detect if state contains a URL, and then route to said URL, but what is the best way of going about this, as in passing/retrieving state with `loginWithRedirect`?

Thanks for the input, new to Auth0 but its very useful so far.

Comment: You can pass in a [`RedirectLoginOptions`](https://auth0.github.io/auth0-vue/interfaces/RedirectLoginOptions.html) object to the [`loginWithRedirect()`](https://auth0.github.io/auth0-vue/interfaces/Auth0VueClient.html#loginWithRedirect) method. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Should `loginWithRedirect()` be called within the route guard if some stored URL is detected, or should it reside in main.js